# Iterate through a datalist to set the visibilty of a control

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist, loops

I have a datalist and a hyperlink control that holds a url. A user creates this datalist through an admin website and not all of the hyperlinks have a link in them. The issue is how to hide the link that doesn't have a url in the database field.

code for the datalist:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlPromoEvents" runat="server" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2" RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblPromoHeading" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("eventHeading") %>' Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#FFFF00" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="promoDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("eventDate", "{0:D}") %>' Font-Size="11pt" ForeColor="#33FF00" />&nbsp;<span style="color: #33ff00; font-size: 12pt">@</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblPromoTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("startTime", "{0:t}") %>' Font-Size="11pt" ForeColor="#33FF00" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblPromoDetails" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("eventDetails") %>' Font-Size="11pt" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="eventLink" Text="Check this out!" CssClass="linkEvent" Visible="false" runat="server" Target="_blank" ToolTip="click to go check out what's happening!" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("eventLink") %>' />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <hr style="width: 480px; height: 1px;  background-color: #ff9900; border-color: #ff9900" />
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

In the code behind I set the datasource with code and now I am stumped on how to reach into the items and control the visibility of the 'check this out' link based upon whether the db field has a link in it or not.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            dtlPromoEvents.DataSource = LoadEvents();

            //filter through the events and turn on visibility for the events that have a live link.


            dtlPromoEvents.DataBind();
        }    
    }

   public static DataSet LoadEvents()
    {
        DataSet eventInfo = new DataSet();

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectBeerGeeksDb"];

        using (SqlConnection selectConnInfo = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapterInfo = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [eventDate], [startTime], [eventHeading], [eventDetails], [eventLink] FROM [promoEvent] WHERE (eventDate + 1 > GETDATE()) ORDER BY eventDate", selectConnInfo);
            selectConnInfo.Open();
            eventInfo.Clear();
            adapterInfo.Fill(eventInfo);
            selectConnInfo.Close();
        }
        return eventInfo;
    }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

rjsteward

Adding the refined code that works on this url:    [http://beergeekspub.com/events.aspx][1]

```
   protected void dtlPromoEvents_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            // Retrieve the Hyperlink control in the current DataListItem.
            HyperLink eLink = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("eventLink");

            // Check if a URL exists, if not then hide the control
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(eLink.NavigateUrl))
            {
                eLink.Visible =false;
            }

        }
    }
```

also the page load databinds the datalist -

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            dtlPromoEvents.DataSource = LoadEvents();

            dtlPromoEvents.DataBind();
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the ItemDataBound event to capture the controls as they're being bound to the data.  In this event, you can check to see if the URL exists, and if not, hide the hyperlink control.

How to: Customize DataList Items at Run Time:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y92e1ze(v=VS.100).aspx#Y900

DataList.ItemDataBound Event
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound(v=VS.100).aspx

For example, modifying the example on the 2nd link (just off the top of my head, and not a C# guy, so this is probably not exact):

```
protected void dtlPromoEvents_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            // Retrieve the Hyperlink control in the current DataListItem.
            HyperLink eLink = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("eventLink");

            // Check if a URL exists, if not then hide the control
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(eLink.NavigateUrl))
            {
                eLink.Visible =false;
            }

        }
    }
```

In the asp markup do this:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlPromoEvents" runat="server" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2" OnItemDataBound="dtlPromoEvents_ItemDataBound" RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" >
```

Comment: @Shawn, it's been a while since I did this kind of thing but I don't believe the hyperlink will have the value assigned yet. Since the binding is just happening. e.Item.DataItem will give the current "row". So one should look at the data to see if the url exists rather than the NavigateURL property. e.Item.DataItem will be of type DataRowView (I think) so ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["eventLink"] will give the specific column for the current row. If it is DBNull then hide the eLink control in your example.

Comment: @ShivKumar - both yours and @ShawnSteward's methods should work equally well, although your method checks for DBNull which may or may not work depending on the database/datamodel design.

Comment: @5arx, how do you "depending on the database/datamodel"? you have to check a database NULL using DBNull.Value and not .net null keyword.

Comment: @ShivKumar - I'm not disputing your use of DBNull.Value. Of course it will work.

My point was that the corresponding field in the database might be an empty string rather than null. It happens, and may be a consideration if the OP graduates to binding to a class library.

Comment: @5arx, I was just curious because I've never done that. Way back when I started with .NET I found out pretty soon that one has to use DBNull.Value and I thought you were implying that something has changed since. What you're saying is the field could be DBNull or empty.

Comment: @ShivKumar - yes exactly. Not disputing your entirely correct checking for DBNull. But I've worked on some apps that were built with non-nullable DB fields which then had DAL-type objects built off them. With varying results ;-)

Comment: The database field accepts a null value and my client just doesn't fill out the admin entry form. He is a smart user, but I can see that a less experienced user may put a non-url text in the field and therefore crash the page. As with all user control content, you can spend you life hardening the code and the user will still break it somehow. I guess I could validate the url itself before allowing it to fire off a browser instance. thanks for the comments.

Comment: @ShivKumar Just to clarify, yes the child controls are all created in the ItemDataBound event.  They just aren't created in the ItemCreated event yet.